# HTML: auto increase height based on other div's height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 `<div>`s as follows. In that one of the `<div>` has panel bar so its height may be increased based on the content of each panel bar. Now I want to increase the height of other two divs based on the height of the `<div>` which has panel bar. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="leftdiv">

</div>

<div class="maindiv">

 //Panel bar is inside this div.

</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
</div>
```

"leftdiv" and "rightdiv" height should be increase base on "maindiv" height???

Comment: This is not a 'proper' answer, but consider looking at this link to see if it is helpful: http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

Comment: try to use `display:table-cell` property for your div.

Comment: Please could you provide the styles for leftdiv, maindiv etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it using css and positioning the divs absolutely or relatively, with margins for the central item.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/o403Ljoq/

Code:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
<div class="leftDiv" >text</div>
<div class="mainDiv">text<div>Something with height</div>
<div style="height:200px;">something else with height</div></div>
<div class="rightDiv" >text</div>

.parentDiv
{
    position:relative;
    background-color:gray;
}
.leftDiv
{
background-color:blue;
 position:absolute; 
 left:0px; 
 top:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 width:100px;
}
.mainDiv
{
background-color:yellow;
 margin-left:100px;
 margin-right:100px;
}
.rightDiv
{
background-color:green; 
 position:absolute; 
 right:0px;
 top:0px; 
 bottom:0px;
 width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/urwbvse0/)

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftdiv">a</div>
    <div class="maindiv">//Panel bar is inside<br/> this div.<br/>//Panel bar is inside<br/> this div.</div>
    <div class="rightdiv">c</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.leftdiv {
    background:red;
    display:table-cell;
}
.maindiv {
    background:green;
    display:table-cell;
}
.rightdiv {
    background:blue;
    display:table-cell;
}
.container{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example using bootstrap (`row col-wrap` class) Try the example in full screen mode

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {

/* top row */
.col .well{ 
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;  
}


.col-base{ 
    margin-top: -15px; 
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.row.base{
    display:none;
}
}


.col-wrap{
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">

<div class="row col-wrap">
<div class="col-sm-4 col">
<div class="well">
<p>A </p>
<p>B </p>
<p>C </p>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="col-sm-4 col">
<div class="well">
<p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
  <p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
  <p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
  <p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
  <p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
  <p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
  <p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
  <p>MAIN CONTAINER</p>
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="col-sm-4 col">
<div class="well">
<p>D </p>
<p>E </p>

</div>
</div>
       
</div>
    

<div class="row base col-wrap">

<div class="col-sm-4 col-base"><div class="well"></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-base"><div class="well"></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-base"><div class="well"></div></div>
</div>
    
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use JavaScript for achieving the result:

```
var commonHeight = $(".maindiv").height();

$(".leftdiv").height(commonHeight);
$(".rightdiv").height(commonHeight);
```

The full example and demo is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pLmp1zpr/

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox to do this.

Wrap your divs in a container.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftdiv"></div>
    <div class="maindiv"></div>
    <div class="rightdiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.leftdiv,.rightdiv,.maindiv{
    flex:1 0;
}
```

[**Here is the DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/tj873tf0/)